# Why GetVaryByCustomString is not called

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, outputcache

output cache is implemented in ASP.NET MVC2 using code below.

`GetVaryByCustomString` method is not called: placing breakpoint to its first line and running application shows that breakpoint is not reached.
Breakpoint in controller Index() is reached.

How to use `VaryByCustom`  in ASP.NET MVC2 ?

Controller:

```
        [OutputCache(VaryByCustom = "user")]
        public ActionResult Index(string _entity, string id)
        {
...
```

Global.asax.cs:

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    public  override string GetVaryByCustomString(HttpContext context, string arg)
    {
        if (arg == "user")
        {
            HttpCookie cookie = context.Request.Cookies["Company"];
            if (cookie != null)
                return Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.Name + "," + cookie.Value;
            return Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.Name;
        }
        return base.GetVaryByCustomString(context, arg);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your OutputCache definition is wrong. You must specify the `Duration`:

```
[OutputCache(VaryByCustom = "user", Duration = 50)]
public ActionResult Index(string _entity, string id)
```

Now your overridden `GetVaryByCustomString` method will be called. Also don't forget that the `GetVaryByCustomString` method will be called only after the controller action has finished executing.

Comment: Thank you. After adding this Vary:* header is sent to browser and this disables browser cache. How to enable browser cache with VaryByCustom?

Answer (score 2):

I just want to mention 2 other causes

If there is any *[NoCache]* attribute in project, *GetVaryByCustomString* will not fire.

If you put

```
Location = OutputCacheLocation.Client,
```

*GetVaryByCustomString* will not fire.

Answer (score 1):

A project that I worked on recently had a global filter preventing output caching from working:

```
public class FilterConfig
{
    public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
    {
        filters.Add(new NoCacheResponseAttribute());
    }
}

public class NoCacheResponseAttribute : BaseActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
       var response = filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Response;
       response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
       response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(-1));
       response.Cache.SetNoStore();
    }
}
```

After commenting the line which adds the filter, output caching started working as expected.